# Replace a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

Which javascript, put after the following code, could prevent googletag.cmd.push function to work as intended?

I tried to add at the bottom something like:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {});
```

But nothing happens.

Here is the code, I just want to break this up, inserting something after it..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement('script');
gads.async = true;
gads.type = 'text/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
googletag.defineSlot('/1045124/_GL_BottomMiddle'    , [728, 90],    'div-gpt-ad-1409922595811-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/1045124/_GL_RightSkyscraper' , [[160, 600], [300, 600]],             'div-gpt-ad-1409922595811-1').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/1045124/_GL_TopLeft'         , [135, 90],                            'div-gpt-ad-1409922595811-2').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/1045124/_GL_TopMiddle'       , [728, 90],    'div-gpt-ad-1409922595811-3').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/1045124/_GL_TopRight'        , [135, 90],                            'div-gpt-ad-1409922595811-4').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/1045124/_GL_Forum', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1412177584435-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
```

EDIT
Ok I am trying to better explain the situation:
I have the above code in a page. I do not want these javascript functions to perform their actual tasks, I want to redefine them, to make them unuseful. Of course I can't just edit that piece of code, otherwise I would not be asking here.
How may I proceed? Example: After that code I insert some javascript that injects some other code on the top of that and disables or removes those functions.

Comment: Could you please explain what actually happen.Couldn't get an idea from your description?

Answer (score 0):

You can overrule a function simply by assigning a new one to it, like this:

```
googletag.cmd.push = function(){}
```

However, this is a VERY bad idea and will almost certainly have terrible side effects, which will probably break the entire library.

Answer (score 0):

```
googletag.cmd.push = function(){}
```

doesn't affect at all the previous function, which would be executed correctly anyway..
He needs something that breaks one of those functions..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).